# merge 2 lists with tuple and list and integer

Tags: python

I have 2 lists  with tuple and list inside them, how could I merge them together that result would be like this

values 6,0 never changes, only values like 3120 can change alost ther can bet multiple integers in the second list like `list1 =  [(6, 0, [3120,2121,14141])]`

```
list3 = [(6, 0, [3120, 3116])]
```

my lists

```
list1 =  [(6, 0, [3120])]
```

and

```
list2 = [(6, 0, [3116])]
```

Comment: What would happen if the first and second values of `list2` are different than those in `list1`, e.g.: if `list2 = [(2, 14, [3116])]`?

Comment: @MrGeek I updated my question

Comment: Will your lists have more than one element?

Comment: @Tomothy32 updated again

Comment: @Chaban33 I think he meant will `list1` and `list2` have more tuples in them?

Comment: @Chaban33 Yes, Mr Geek is right, I meant that will `list1` and `list2` have more than one element inside of them, e.g. `list1 = [(6, 0, [3120, 2121, 14141]), (2, 14, [3116])]]` or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can try it this way, provided the first two items in the tuple won't change as per the question.**

---

```
list1 =  [(6, 0, [3120])]
list2 = [(6, 0, [3116])]

def add_two_lists(list1, list2):
    # Destructure the first element which is a tuple in both lists
    l1_first, l1_second, rest_first = list1[0]
    l2_first, l2second, rest_second = list2[0]
    res_tuple = (l1_first, l1_second, rest_first + rest_second)
    res_list = [res_tuple]
    return res_list

print(add_two_lists(list1, list2))
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick for you:

```
list1 =  [(6, 0, [3120])]

list2 = [(6, 0, [3116])]

temp_list1 = list(list1[0])

temp_list2 = list(list2[0])

temp_list1[2].append(temp_list2[2][0])

final_tuple= tuple(temp_list1)

list3=[]
list3.append(final_tuple)

print(list3)
```

prints:

```
[(6, 0, [3120, 3116])]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this for your example input:

```
list3 = [list1[0][:2] + tuple([list1[0][2] + list2[0][2]])]
# [(6, 0, [3120, 3116])]
```

Works for multiple values in the list:

```
list1 = [(6, 0, [3120,2121,14141])]
list2 = [(6, 0, [3116])]

list3 = [list1[0][:2] + tuple([list1[0][2] + list2[0][2]])]

print(list3)
# [(6, 0, [3120, 2121, 14141, 3116])]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do as below assuming length of list1 and list 2 are equal.

```py
list1 =  [(6, 0, [2,4,8]),(3, 5, [3,5,7]),]
list2 =  [(6, 0, [10,12,14]),(3, 5, [9,11,13,15]),]

final_list = []

for i, v in enumerate(list1):
    list3 = [(list1[i])] + [(list2[i])]
    final = list3[0][:2] + tuple([list3[0][2] + list3[1][2]])
    final_list.append(final)
```

```py
print(final_list)
```

```sh
Out[1]: [(6, 0, [2, 4, 8, 10, 12, 14]), 
         (3, 5, [3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15])]
```